# Многоклассовая классификация (классификация типов стекла)

Tags: классификация

Работаю с классическим датасетом про классификацию типов стекла (работаю в учебных целях).
Частичный фрагмент, полученного датафрейма:

[image: Фрагмент датафрейма]

> (Далее дословная цитата фрагмента задания) Для моделирования необходимо выбрать целевую переменную – такой признак, который принимает только два значения (метки классов). Если такой двоичный признак в данных отсутствует, выбрать такой дискретный или непрерывный числовой признак, и сконструировать на его основе целевой признак (добавить новую колонку в датафрейм). Выполнить кодирование целевого признака значениями 0 и 1 (0 соответствует одной метке класса, 1 – другой).

Очевидно, что необходимо построить модель, которая будет определять тип стекла (переменная "Type"), но эта переменная **не является бинарной** (принимает значения **от 1 до 7**). Вот в этом самый главный вопрос: "Как сконструировать **бинарный** признак на основе другого признака, который принимает **семь** различных значений?

Comment: Условие вида `признак = 3` - бинарное. Заведите семь таких условий.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос очень не четко сформулирован. Но! Если у вас семь классов  (т.е. Type от 1 до 7)/ можно сделать следующее. Вы создаете дополнительно семь колонок, по количеству классов стекла. И там в каждой колонке появляется уже бинарное значение, или это стекло принадлежит к классу (1) или не принадлежит (0).